# Is the Axiom of Finite Additivity even an axiom?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathbb{P}\left(#1\right)}$
In Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference* (2nd ed., p. 9), there is the **Axiom of Finite Additivity**. That is, if $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a sample space $S$ and $A, B\in \mathcal{B}$ are two disjoint events, then 
$$\P{A \cup B} = \P{A} +\P{B}\text{.}$$

**Is this even an axiom, assuming we have the definition of a probability measure**? Casella and Berger define a probability "function" (I prefer measure) as follows:

> **Definition 1.2.4** Given a sample space $S$ and an associated sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$, a probability function is a function $P$ with
>   domain $\mathcal{B}$ that satisfies:
>
> 1. $P(A) \geq 0$
> 2. $P(S) = 1$
> 3. If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{B}$ are pairwise disjoint, then $P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_i)$.

It is clear that that $\P{\varnothing} = 0$ from this definition. In $\mathcal{B}$, we know $\varnothing$ exists, and $\P{S} = \P{S \cup \varnothing} = \P{S}+\P{\varnothing} = 1$, so that $1 + \P{\varnothing} = 1$, or $\P{\varnothing} = 0$.

An event is defined as a subset of $S$. Take two events $A$, $B \in \mathcal{B}$. We can write $A$ and $B$ as a disjoint union of two sets:
$$\begin{align}
A &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^{c}) \\
B &= (A \cap B) \cup (B \cap A^{c})\text{.}\end{align}$$
and $$A \cup B = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^{c}) \cup (B \cap A^{c})\text{.}$$It follows that 
$$\begin{align}
\P{A} &= \P{A \cap B} + \P{A \cap B^{c}} \\
\P{B} &= \P{A \cap B} + \P{B \cap A^{c}} \\
\P{A \cup B} &= \P{A \cap B} + \P{A \cap B^{c}} + \P{B \cap A^{c}}\text{,}
\end{align}$$
so that 
$$\P{A \cup B} = \P{A}+\P{B}-\P{A \cap B}\text{.}$$

Suppose now that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Then $A \cap B = \varnothing$ and as proven before, $\P{\varnothing} = 0$, implying the Axiom of Finite Additivity.

Comment: You're right, it's a theorem that's a consequence of the Axiom of countable additivity. However, the name "axiom" is useful in order to consider cases where the ordinary axiom might be weakened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You repeatedly *used* the Axiom of Finite Additivity in your proofs (starting with the proof of $P(\emptyset)=0$). To correctly show that finite additivity follows from countable additivity, just let $A_1=A$, $A_2=B$ and $A_i=\emptyset$ for $i>2$. Then the equality $$P(A\cup B)=P(\bigcup_i A_i)=P(A)+P(B)+``\infty\cdot P(\emptyset)\!"$$ can only hold if $P(\emptyset)=0$.
However, nobody said that the given collection of axioms is minimal. For example the group axioms are also often listed in a redundant (=non-minimal) way.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Have to remember that finite additivity does not mean countable additivity.